# Mongoid3 + FactoryGirl Incompatible?

Tags: devise, factory-bot, mongoid3

I just upgrade to Mongoid3 and Im getting a TON of these errors:

```
TypeError:
   can't convert String into Integer
```

The issue is always when Im trying to build a model that belongs_to another model and I assign the referenced model:

```
@entry = FactoryGirl.create(:entry_image, user_id: @user.id, day: 18, month: 6)
```

It seems to be the "user_id: @user.id" part. Ive tried:

```
@entry = FactoryGirl.build(:entry_image, day: 18, month: 6)
@entry.user = @user
@entry.save
```

Same error every time.

Here is the factory file:

```
  FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
      name 'Test User'
      email 'example@example.com'
      password 'please'
      password_confirmation 'please'
      pin '1234'
      default_time_zone 'America/New_York'
    end
  ...
```

Im using devise, here is the controller macro we run:

```
  module ControllerMacros

  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      #user.confirm! # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory. Only necessary if you are using the confirmable module
      sign_in @user
    end
  end

  end
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
> 1.9.3p194 :016 > user = User.all[0]
 => #<User _id: 503e9c807adf9d6551000001, _type: nil, email: "joe@email.com", encrypted_password: "$5a$10$Mt1kx/TtbDma4gVtcTLdLeeP6tcSiF2AJkjeJmv73/U5OWF.M34v.", remember_created_at: 2012-08-29 23:30:17 UTC, sign_in_count: 3, current_sign_in_at: 2012-08-29 23:30:17 UTC, last_sign_in_at: 2012-08-29 22:49:57 UTC, current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", s3_access_key: #<Moped::BSON::Binary type=:generic length=24>, s3_secret_key: #<Moped::BSON::Binary type=:generic length=48>, pin: nil, default_time_zone: "America/New_York", name: "Joe Smith"> 
1.9.3p194 :017 > e = FactoryGirl.create(("entry_image").to_s, user_id: user.id, items: [ FactoryGirl.build(:image, user_id: user.id) ])
TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/set.rb:185:in `include?'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/set.rb:185:in `include?'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.5/lib/mongoid/callbacks.rb:140:in `block (3 levels) in cascadable_children'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.5/lib/mongoid/callbacks.rb:139:in `each'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.5/lib/mongoid/callbacks.rb:139:in `block (2 levels) in cascadable_children'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.5/lib/mongoid/relations/accessors.rb:103:in `without_autobuild'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.5/lib/mongoid/callbacks.rb:133:in `block in cascadable_children'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.5/lib/mongoid/callbacks.rb:131:in `each_pair'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.5/lib/mongoid/callbacks.rb:131:in `cascadable_children'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.5/lib/mongoid/callbacks.rb:95:in `run_callbacks'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activemodel-3.2.0/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:53:in `run_validations!'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activemodel-3.2.0/lib/active_model/validations.rb:179:in `valid?'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.5/lib/mongoid/validations.rb:78:in `valid?'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activemodel-3.2.0/lib/active_model/validations.rb:187:in `invalid?'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.5/lib/mongoid/persistence/insertion.rb:22:in `prepare'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mongoid-3.0.5/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/insert.rb:26:in `persist'
... 4 levels...
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:15:in `[]'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:15:in `create'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:12:in `block in result'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `tap'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:23:in `block in run'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:19:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
    from (irb):17
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/lee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace. That one line doesn't provide much context.

Comment: @janders223 I added a full stack trace above, thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Here's what I don't get. You are calling for a `:entry_image` factory, yet your factory is defined as `:user`? Also, why are you setting the association, and not letting FactoryGirl define it?

Comment: this is from an rspec test where we log the user in so the tests will fail if i dont specify that user object.

Comment: Your `user.id` is clearly a string, not an integer. Looks like something validating that `user_id` is an integer.

Comment: Its definitely a string, that is how mongoid/mongo stores _ids. The weird thing is there's nothing new validating the id, its the exact same code as before just mongoid updated to 3.0.

Comment: I'm also getting errors in FG after upgrading to Mongo3. Think I'm just gonna downgrade, app was working fine before.